# How to use em to accurately set the font-size of a child?

Tags: html, css, fonts

As per the MDN article on the [font-size article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size):

> In order to calculate the em equivalent for any pixel value required, you can use this formula:
> `em = desired element pixel value / parent element font-size in pixels`

But this does not seem to apply when the child has a *different font-family* than the parent. The linked MDN article does not mention anything about the font-family being of concern. Here is a quick example:

```css
#container {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: serif;
}

#child {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p id="container">
  Container text
  <span id="child"> and child</span>
</p>
```

You can check in DevTools that `#child` has a computed font-size of 18px whereas its `#parent` has a computed font-size of 16px. This is unexpected because `font-size: 1em;` should be a 1x multiplier over the parent's font-size, so both of them should have the same font-size of 18px.

**Question:** Why does `1em` not give the same font-size as that of the parent? If `em` would not work, what alternatives do I have to set the font-size of child as a multiple of the font size of the parent?

Comment: When I inspect your snippet the elemnts both show a computed font-size of 18px - just as expected. However, the monospace text is **visually bigger** due to its wider design, larger x-height and bolder stem widths.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, suppose the `font-size` of the `<body>` of the page is set to 16px. If the font-size you want is 12px, then you should specify 0.75em (because 12/16 = 0.75). Similarly, if you want a font size of 10px, then specify 0.625em (10/16 = 0.625); for 22px, specify 1.375em (22/16).

So you want the size to be `16px` then you divide desired font-size with parent font-size (for your case parent `font-size` is `18px`).

```
em = 16/18 (which will be 0.88888888888em)
```

```css
 #container {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: serif;
}

#child {
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 0.88888888888em;
}
```

```html
   <p id="container">
    Container text
    <span id="child"> and child</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hey Shahzaib, your answer doesn't seem valid. If you check the size of `<span>` using DevTools, you'll see the font-size is actually ~11px.  https://imgur.com/a/ikXvV8G

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to define the parent font-size, now it works as intended.